# where is whoami data derived from?

Tags: windows, web-services, desktop-application, development-environment

From a Windows command prompt if you enter whoami, you're domain\username is returned.  Where is this information stored?  Also, can the information be updated?

I have two users that are experiencing an issue where their username is not in the correct case / format.  The expected format is domain\username but the users are returned domain\Username .

whoami:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299.aspx

Comment: It gets the user's SID from the current token and then calls `LookupAccountSid` to get the account name and domain. For this it makes a remote procedure call to the LSA process, which queries the SAM database for a local account and otherwise queries trusted domain controllers. Can't you just modify the account name in the Active Directory administration tool?

Comment: AD displays the user as domain\username.  Waitning to hear back if they are logging in using domain\Username or domain\username.